# Flyway migrate says schema is up to date

Tags: flyway

I have installed Flyway in my server and trying to execute a My-sql file which I placed in sql folder of flyway.

I have done Flyway baseline, and when I run `flyway migrate` it says "Schema `xyz` is up to date. No migration necessary." No matter what I do it always gives me the same result.

My sql files are named `1__act.sql`, `2__act.sql`, `3__act.sql`.

My config file has

```
flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:port/xyz
flyway.user=flywayuser
flyway.password=flywaypassword
flyway.baselineVersion=1
```

Answer (score 7):

You haven't followed the [naming conventions for Versioned SQL migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/sql), they should be prefixed with a `V`. e.g. `V1__act.sql`.

Note that the prefix is configurable, but above is the default.

Answer (score -1):

`/src/main/resources/db/migration` needs to be a source folder in Eclipse/Spring Tool Suite. Right-click it, Build Path, Use as Source Folder.

Comment: It might not be the answer for people like the OP who do their naming convention wrong but it's definitely an answer for the error message in the question title.